# How to save the Scanned QR code images in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, qr-code, barcode

I am using flutter_barcode_scanner package to scan QR code ,it's working but
I want to save the image of Qr Code , I try qrscan to generate from the resultat for the first scan but it's not the same QR Code.

[image: image scanned]

and the qr generated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try that plugin out

[screenshot 0.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)

Hope will help you

Comment: this package it's for make screen shot

Comment: as far as i get the plugin description, you can snap a screnshot of any widget,